# Error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-7

can any one tell me what am i doing wrong here?

```css
 $getIDtascart = DB::table('temp_cart')->where('id_user',$getUser)->select('id_tas')->get();
 TasRajut::destroy($getIDtascart);
```

`$getIDtascart` is array

thankyou

**EDITED :**

the error in stack trace is `PDOStatement::bindValue` .
this is full error

```css
$statement->bindValue(

                is_string($key) ? $key : $key + 1,

                $value,

                $pdoParam
            );
```

thankyou

Comment: Can you please provide the full error message with a stack trace, if possible?

Comment: are you  wanting to clear multiple records at once?  ->get() always returns a collection.

Comment: *"`$getIDtascart` is array"* - No, it's Actually a [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections). If you call `->toArray()`, then it is an Array. If you want to delete a bunch of `TasRajut` records based on the returned Ids, then maybe `TasRajut::whereIn('id', DB::table('temp_cart')->where('id_user',$getUser)->pluck('id_tas'))->delete()`.

Comment: @TimLewis thankyou so much , that code fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete some records data try to use ->delete() instead ->get()

```
$getIDtascart = DB::table('temp_cart')->where('id_user',$getUser)->select('id_tas')->delete();
```

and you no longer need this line

```
TasRajut::destroy($getIDtascart);
```